# react native IOS where i can find main jsbundle

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, bundle

```
    - (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
```

I created a new project and this code points to a file named main jsbundle, but I searched inside the project and didn't find it

Is this file hidden or the code is unnecessary or do I have to create this file manually

Comment: could you explain more or give some steps of what is happening so you get this error ?

Comment: If you are running in debug env. that is served by metro bundler (react native start). If you want a offline one, use react-native bundle to get it.

Comment: @Guku there is no error but i have question what is this file for 
main.jsbundle
and where i can find this file